# LinkageError occurred while loading main class (java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError) (Java)

Tags: java, jar

Было установлено jdk 9 потом сменил на jdk 12. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и в Intellij поменял параметры Project Structure

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при попытке открыть созданный с помощью Intellij jar файл, выдает такой результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подумал, что ок, кажется все из за того, что я забыл сделать перезагрузку системы. Сделал перезагрузку а проблема как была так и осталась.

Кстати, jar тоже удалил и снова создал, тоже ноль эффекта.

Вопрос: Как это понять?

---

обновление вопроса в 12.10.2019

вот, что я заметил...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение данной проблемы. Проблема была решена путем внесения некоторых изменений в окне "Переменные среды". 1) удалил C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath; 2) добавил новую переменную PATH, назначил ее значение %JAVA_HOME%\bin;  ... и все заработала. Помог мне найти решение данный форум https://coderanch.com/t/708054/java/JDK-Installation-include-JRE.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно в Idea нужно подправить настройку в **File>Settings**
далее в окне 
**Build, Execution, Deploying > Compiler > Java Compiler** 
Там необходимо установить необходимую версию в поле "Target bytecode version"

Comment: попробовал - не помогает.

Comment: А в **File>Project** Structure поле **Language Level** подправили (пункт **Modules**) ?

Comment: да. даже на Х Experimental features поставил.

Comment: проблема как была так и осталась.

Comment: Я бы убедилась, что старя версия java удалена. Наберите **java -version** и **javac -version**. Не уверна что нужна пременная JAVAC, удалила бы. Пересоздала (или создала новый) бы профаил запуска jar-файла, что бы запускать с Idea (Я же правильно понимаю чтовы с с командной строки запускайте?). Ну если не поможет, напишите мне в мессенджер или на почту.

Comment: кажется нашел виновника... вопрос обновил, можете посмотреть

Comment: Нашел решение проблемы. Вопрос снят.

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за дополнительную поддержку. (даю вам +5 баллов хотя бы за то, что откликнулись и помогли по крайней мере дали подсказку, речь о java-version и javac-version)

Comment: Thanks! I am glad that you managed the matter